# How to input text in to the frontmost app by program automatically (with private API) in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi, tweak

My Tweak is running inside `SpringBoard`, I want it be able to input text to first responder of the frontmost application.I tried the code below, but it only works for the subviews of `SpringBoard`, such as the search bar on of home screen, but not any other apps, does anyone know how to do it?

```
@interface UIKeyboardImpl : NSObject
+(UIKeyboardImpl*)sharedInstance;
-(void)addInputString:(NSString*)string;
@end

void input(const char * text)
{
    UIKeyboardImpl * keyboardImpl = [UIKeyboardImpl sharedInstance];
    [keyboardImpl addInputString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:text]];
}
```

Comment: Just an idea, as I don't know if this would work, but maybe you could hook any app using the framework (I presume UIKit) and do the same stuff.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that.but that way will influence every app, what maybe ill-flavored and untrusted, how do you think?

Comment: If you want to modify things in the `frontmost application` you'll need to inject your tweak there. Using  "com.apple.UIKit" as filter will let you do that.

Comment: Yes, I tried that method, but I can't inject `CFMessagePort` to all of the applications, in most of them I can't `CFMessagePortCreateLocal ` a `CFMessagePort`,would you take a look at:  :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28113564/how-to-communicate-between-applications-in-ios?noredirect=1#comment44602939_28113564